# How can we find the smallest number $n$ such that $2^{2^n} + 1$ is not a prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can we find the smallest Fermat number (i.e. in the form  $2^{2^n} + 1, n \in \mathbb N$) that is not prime and show that it is indeed not a prime? Yes, when $n=5$, it is not a prime. How can we find $n=5$ , other than just factoring the Fermat number when $n=5$?

Is there a shorter and more elegant solution?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Primality_of_Fermat_numbers

Comment: Use any resource about fermat numbers :)

Comment: When n=5 it is not a prime. But I ask how to find it. Obviosly we can factor all fermat numbers out till we find n=5 is not a prime. But is there a simpler way?

Comment: There is (problably) no other method. That why Fermat thought $F_5$ (in afact any $F_n$) was prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, we can only show $F_n$ is not prime by factoring it. But there's a faster way to factor it than checking every prime number less than $\sqrt {F_n}$.

We use the fact that every factor of $2^{2^n}+1$ with $n\ge2$ is of the form $k*2^{n+2}+1$. So to show $F_5$ is not prime, we only have to check numbers of the form $128k+1$. Then we get
$$129\nmid F_5$$
$$257\nmid F_5$$
$$385\nmid F_5$$
$$513\nmid F_5$$
$$641\mid F_5$$
So we know $F_5$ is not prime.

Comment: Actually we can just start with $641$ as $129$, $385$, $513$ are not prime, and $257=F_3$ cannot be a factor of $F_5$ since Fermat numbers with different indices are coprime.

Answer (score 3):

This is a stunning way of proof that I've seen in a book long ago but could not forget...

Let $a=2^7$ and $b=5$.
Then $$1+ab-b^4=1+(a-b^3)b=1+3b=2^4$$ so
\begin{align}
F_5&=2^{32}+1\\
&=2^4a^4+1\\
&=(1+ab-b^4)a^4+1\\
&=(1+ab)((1+a^2b^2)(1-ab)+a^4)
\end{align}
Since $1+ab=1+2^7\cdot5=641$, we have$$641|F_5$$

Comment: The proof is by G. Bennet and I have seen it in David M. Burton's book *Elementary Number Theory*.

Answer (score 2):

$$F_0 = 2^1 + 1 = 3$$
$$F_1 = 2^2 + 1 = 5$$
$$F_2 = 2^4 + 1 = 17$$
$$F_3 = 2^8 + 1 = 257$$
$$F_4 = 2^{16} + 1 = 65537$$
$$F_5 = 2^{32} + 1 = 4294967297=641\times 6700417$$

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to find n=5 other than just factoring fermat numbers one by one? A simpler way?

Comment: @Olcayto: As far as I know, there is no other method.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65537_%28number%29): $65537$ is the largest known prime number of the form $2^{2^{n}}+1$.

And it is computed with $n=4$, so the answer to your question is $n=5$.

Comment: But how to show that it is not prime when n=5? Is there any other way of showing it other than factoring?

Comment: @Olcayto: Factoring is the only thing that comes to mind. In a certain way, it reminds me of the fact that there is no general solution to polynomial equations of degree equal or higher than $5$, so perhaps *Galois Group* theory can be used here. I sincerely doubt that anyone has ever made a relation between these two, but that question is probably more suitable for the experts on MO.